# How to log managed bean name and action method being invoked in a servlet filter

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I am working on a web application built on JSF 2 Mojarra. I have a requirement to log some instrumentation information through my servlet filter. To do this I also need to know which ManagedBean and which method is being invoked.

Is there a way to get this information? I can't access `FacesContext` as filter is invoked before the request reaches Faces Servlet.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this using Servlet Filter only, but it is better to use a PhaseListener. Refer to [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) to have a complete tutorial on this matter.

Comment: The request processing cycle starts only with the invocation of the Faces Servlet. Although, you can get the session-scoped beans without using `FacesContext`, but it would be too early to try to get others like request-scoped. What kind of information is "instrumentation information"? I also think it would be better to use phase listeners instead like Luiggi suggested.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - But phase listener comes into action after FacesServlet. My requirement is to log time between the request hitting my server and response leaving my server. Using phase listener I will not get the exact time.

Comment: Well, there's no way to know the exact managed bean and method if you don't know what you have invoked. Note that this info is given by the `FacesContext`, no one else. Still, if you want to do it in that way, you should have to pass parameters on **every request** marking the managed bean name and the invoked method (yes, pretty clumsy).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Just curious. It should be available somewhere in the request body, if not then how FacesServlet will be delegating to the correct ManagedBean.

Comment: If you see the generated HTML code, you will **never** find the name of your managed bean nor your action. It's a *mystery* how Faces Servlet solves this (and it must be kept like that).

Comment: Yes I have already searched my html, the request body through Fiddler. But no luck. Posted here to see if someone has tried this out.

Comment: BalusC already did it and posted that blog entry (just in case).

Comment: I guess you could do something by providing your own EL resolvers. You could also look at switching from managed beans to CDI and taking advantage of [CDIs richer feature set](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjehi.html).

Comment: @McDowell - I do have my own EL resolver, but how does that help here? Regarding CDI I am on WebSphere 7, no support for JEE 6.

Comment: If you provide all the `ValueExpression` instances you should be able to instrument the return values with (for example) decorators. Or you could provide a custom `Application` instance that instruments `MethodExpression`s via the `ExpressionFactory`. Personally, I'd look at something like AspectJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gather that you want to log the `UICommand` component being invoked. A servlet filter is insuitable for that as it has no access to the `FacesContext`, let alone the `UIViewRoot` which you ultimately need to traverse. The `FacesContext` (and inherently also the `UIViewRoot`, et.al) are created by the `FacesServlet` which is as being a decent servlet completely conform the [servlet spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) invoked *after* all filters. It's therefore impossible to get a hand of the `FacesContext` inside a servlet filter. True, there are [ways](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingTheFacesContextInsideHttpServletOrFilter) to create your own `FacesContext` instance, but this is absolutely not recommended if there exist a "right way" to achieve the requirement.

You should be using the right tool for the job, which is in this particular case a phase listener. Here's a kickoff example of how a phase listener look like and should be registered:

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right before the RESTORE_VIEW phase.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // Do your job here which should run right after the RESTORE_VIEW phase.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

You can change the `getPhaseId()` outcome to your insight, e.g. `PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE`, then the phase listener will kick in on before and after the render response phase.

Here's a concrete kickoff example which does the job you're looking for (finding the command component being invoked and logging its action method expression):

```
public class InvokedCommandComponentLogger implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP. The view hasn't been restored yet at that point, so the component tree wouldn't be available anyway.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();

        if (context.isPostback()) {
            UICommand component = findInvokedCommandComponent(context);

            if (component != null) {
                String methodExpression = component.getActionExpression().getExpressionString();
                System.out.println("Method expression of the action being invoked: " + methodExpression);
            }
        }
    }

    private UICommand findInvokedCommandComponent(FacesContext context) {
        Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        Set<String> clientIds = new HashSet<>();

        if (context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
            clientIds.add(params.get("javax.faces.source")); // This covers <f:ajax> inside UICommand.
        } else {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals(entry.getValue())) { // This covers UIForm and UICommand components.
                    clientIds.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        EnumSet<VisitHint> hints = EnumSet.of(VisitHint.SKIP_UNRENDERED);
        final UICommand[] found = new UICommand[1];
        context.getViewRoot().visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(context, clientIds, hints), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
                if (target instanceof UICommand) {
                    found[0] = (UICommand) target;
                    return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                } else {
                    return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
                }
            }
        });

        return found[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I take up your approach and capture the method expression in phase listener. I further add it to request and finally get it in my filter after the request processing.

Comment: One issue that is coming up is when I am using composite component. Instead of actual method expression I am getting #{cc.attrs.action}, which is the expression in my composite implementation. Is there a work around available?