# How to log all JSF2 interactions: actions, listeners, etc

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am attempting to develop a more refined access log for a JSF2 based application.  I'm interested in not only logging URL access, but also logging any actions, action methods, listeners that were invoked in the request.  I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330474/how-to-log-managed-bean-name-and-action-method-being-invoked-in-a-servlet-filter) first, and it did a good job of getting me started.  There was a minor gotcha I found with Primefaces, but it was easily correctable.

The problems that I'm running into now is that f:ajax and p:ajax calls that identify listeners are not logged.

Example:

```
<f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.onChange()}" />
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onSelect()}" />
```

I'd like to include that expression string "myBean.doSomething()" in my log.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here's what I got so far:

```
public class AccessLogPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();

    String action = null;
    if (context.isPostback()) {
        action = findInvokedCommand(context);
    }

    // Log...
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    AccessLogUtils.logEntry(req, action);
}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
}

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
}

private String findInvokedCommand(final FacesContext facesContext) {
    Map<String, String> params = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    Set<String> clientIds = new HashSet<>();
    String behaviorEvent = params.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");

    if (facesContext.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
        // This covers <f:ajax> inside UICommand.
        clientIds.add(params.get("javax.faces.source"));
    } else {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            // This covers UIForm and UICommand components.
            if (entry.getKey().equals(entry.getValue())
            // This covers Primefaces p:link and p:commandButton (no value passed)
                    || entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                clientIds.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

    EnumSet<VisitHint> hints = EnumSet.of(VisitHint.SKIP_UNRENDERED);
    final UICommand[] found = new UICommand[1];
    facesContext.getViewRoot().visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(facesContext, clientIds, hints),
            new VisitCallback() {
                @Override
                public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
                    if (target instanceof UICommand) {
                        found[0] = (UICommand) target;
                        return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                    } else {
                        return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
                    }
                }
            });

    if (found[0] != null) {
        return found[0].getActionExpression().getExpressionString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}